# PHP ARRAY display grouped data from the array based on date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, range

I have this query

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT type, count(*), date FROM tracking WHERE htcode='$htG' AND type IN ('viewed', 'shared', 'printed', 'emailed', 'used') GROUP BY type, date ORDER BY date ASC");
```

This code:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo $result['date'] .' / ' .$result['type'].' = ' .$result['count(*)'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

gives me :

```
2012-02-01 / viewed = 2
2012-02-03 / emailed = 1
2012-02-04 / shared = 1
2012-02-05 / viewed = 1
2012-02-07 / viewed = 2
2012-02-07 / shared = 3
2012-02-07 / emailed = 1
2012-02-07 / printed = 1
```

How can i take the query array and pull all (viewed, shared, emailed, printed, used) **for today, for yesterday, and for a date range (last 30 days for example)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all results for a specific date range, don't group by date; instead use a WHERE clause to limit the date of the count. Otherwise the query is very similar.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT type, count(*) FROM tracking WHERE htcode = '$htG' AND type IN ('viewed', 'shared', 'printed', 'emailed', 'used') AND date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date' GROUP BY type");
```

Here's just the query itself formatted over several lines for clarity:

```
SELECT type, count(*)
FROM tracking
WHERE htcode = '$htG'
  AND type IN ('viewed', 'shared', 'printed', 'emailed', 'used')
  AND date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date'
GROUP BY type
```

Just make sure you set the values for `$start_date` and `$end_date` first. For example, for today you'd just set them both to this:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Note that `date('Y-m-d')` is just today's date in a format like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

For yesterday, you'd pass in yesterday's timestamp into the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, but use the same format:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));
```

And for the past thirty days, you'd start 30 days ago and end today:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('30 days ago'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

You can do it like this for any start/end date. Note that I'm using [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which lets you use a lot of English phrases to specify timestamps rather than having to do date arithmetic.

Also, since you will be doing the query multiple times, it would probably make sense to separate out the logic into its own function:

```
function report_range($htG, $start_date, $end_date) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT type, count(*) FROM tracking WHERE htcode = '$htG' AND type IN ('viewed', 'shared', 'printed', 'emailed', 'used') AND date >= '$start_date' AND date <= '$end_date' GROUP BY type");

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo $start_date . '-' . $end_date . ' / ' . $result['type'] . ' = '  . $result['count(*)'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Then run it with something like this (last 30 days in this example):

```
report_range($htG, date('Y-m-d', strtotime('30 days ago')), date('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben.. I want to display 4 different results. Today, yesterday, last month and last year. that is why i thought i would use PHP to sort the dates out.. What would you suggest?

Comment: alternatively you can use `WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'` for better readability.

Comment: @DanielHunter, I added examples showing how to do today, yesterday, and the past 30 days. For year, do you just mean 365 days? If so, you can use the same format as for the past 30 days, just with 365.

Comment: @Ben, yeah 365... but, i want to display all results simultaneously, with this method would i have to do 4 queries?

Comment: Yes. Four queries like this should all be fast. Just make sure in your database you put an index on the combined `(htcode, type, date)` (and whatever other indexes you need).

Comment: You could also do one query like the one in your question, grouped by date, and then use php to separate them into the date ranges in question. But that would much slower, use more memory, and be a lot more difficult to code than just querying the database four times.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I want speed and ease, so four queries it is! I Really appreciate the help.